Postgresql last_autovacuum and last_autoanalyze
I have a few tables that ere 1 TB+. The columns last_autovacuum and last_autoanalyze in pg_stat_user_tables have NULLs for these tables. The n_dead_tup to n_live_tup ratio is 0.0001. A few questions, can I rely on the n_dead_tup and n_live_tup numbers? The tables have a large number of inserts and a few updates, no deletes. If I manually vacuum and analyze these tables, will the columns get updated? PostgreSQL version is 13.5

Don't use 13.5. Update to 13.latest.
n_dead_tup usually is accurate (unless you just ran VACUUM (FULL) on the table), but I find that n_live_tup isn't always. I'd use pg_class.reltuples instead, just like autovacuum does.
A manual VACUUM and ANALYZE will update the values.
